# How to lock tabs in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there a way to lock a desired tab in Thunderbird to prevent it from being accidentally closed?

Comment: [TB Tabloc :: Add-ons for Thunderbird](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tb-tabloc/)?

Comment: Last updated 2009 and works with Thunderbird 3. Now we have 2019 and Thunderbird 60. The add-on is not compatible with the current version of the program